# Flex: Backgroundimage not showing in list

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have a custom component that has an background image. 
But when you generate this component by an ItemRenderer in a List, the background image is gone.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is an image. The first element is not generated in a list and has a background image. The other three are part of a List and have no background image.

[image]

Here is the code of the MXML of the List

```
<mx:VBox>
    <solutionItems:displaySolutionItem  />  <!-- This element shows the background image -->                            
    <mx:List selectable="false"
         useRollOver="false" 
         id="listControllers" 
         backgroundAlpha="1"
         dataProvider="{controllers}" >
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>      
                <solutionItems:displaySolutionItem /> <!-- These elements have nog background image -->                             
            </fx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:List>      
</mx:VBox>
```

And here is the code of `<solutionItems:displaySolutionItem />`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    backgroundImage="{itemBackGround}"
    backgroundSize="100%">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[


            [Bindable]
            [Embed(source="assets/Components/ContainerBackgrounds/BoxBg.png", scaleGridLeft="5", scaleGridRight="50", scaleGridTop="5", scaleGridBottom="50")]
            private var itemBackGround:Class;


        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox
        paddingBottom="10"
        paddingLeft="10"
        paddingRight="10"
        paddingTop="10">        

        <mx:CheckBox id="chbControllerItem" label="NSL-4601" styleName="titleRed" />                    
        <mx:HBox>                       
            <mx:Image width="67" height="50" id="loader1" source="@Embed(source='assets/Components/ContainerBackgrounds/BoxBg.png')"/> 
            <mx:HBox>
                <mx:VBox>
                    <mx:Label text="Cube size" styleName="formLabel" height="12" />
                    <mx:Label text="Cube config" styleName="formLabel" height="12" />
                    <mx:Label text="Display res" styleName="formLabel" height="12" />
                    <mx:Label text="DPI" styleName="formLabel" height="12" />
                    <mx:Label text="Price" styleName="formLabel" height="12" />
                </mx:VBox>

                <mx:Box>
                    <mx:Label text="50''" height="12" />
                    <mx:Text text="2x3 (1224mm x 3264mm)" height="12" />
                    <mx:Label text="WXGA (1360x768)" height="12" />
                    <mx:Label text="72 dpi" height="12" />
                    <mx:Label text="€ 101.000,00" height="12" />
                </mx:Box>

            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Canvas>
```

It is probably something small, but I can not find it.

Comment: Did you try removing the scalegrid values from the embed directive and check?

Comment: @user700284 Thaks for your reply. Yes I did, but there was no difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will get around the problem:

1. Remove the backgroundImage="{itemBackGround}" from the Canvas element of the itemRenderer
2. Add the following before the VBox in the itemRenderer class. I tested it out and it works fine:

   ```
   <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" backgroundImage="{itemBackGround}" backgroundSize="100%"/>
   ```

If your find a better way, sure update your question to let us know,

Brian

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the alpha, or backgroundAlpha properties on your List or perhaps in the itemRenderer?

I'm guessing that the List is either drawing something on top of the background, or preventing the background from being drawn.  You'd have to step through code to know for sure, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I set the backgroundAlpha to 0 of the List, I do not see the background image. So I guess the list prevents the background from beeing drawn. How do I know this for sure? And how to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: @Vinzcent You'll have to step through framework code and see if you can figure out what's going on in terms of itemRenderers; how they are created and initialized.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this, but look like 
*component is not creating multiple instance/copies of image for each renderer*

possible solution may be is,  *load image* in any **Singleton/Constant Class** like in **Model** and **NOT** in **component/list** and use *Model's attribute reference* in *component/list* i.e. one copy for all renderer.

Hopes this works